# Header menu height increases but nothing happens in HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a problem that this website's Header menu :
[آسفالت](http://rahsaz.com/)

is increasing it's height . if you stay at website for about 2-3 minutes , header menu will become whole of your page and you need to scroll to see other content of website .
but i couldn't find any css rules that's doing this . also i didn't find anything in JS files .
What is the problem ?

Comment: Mind showing us the code on a Fiddle? Can't do much but speculate without some sort of visual code? ? But it sounds like something is looping to increase size on increments of a set time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be in the orbit slider code : at each slide the picture loses 2px in its height and the #header-outer div, that doesn't have an height property, seems to increase.

Without a sample code to try is really difficult to help you, but as workaround/solution, you can add an height property set to the initial height of #header-outer div (92px)

Your style.css entry should be like this (added height only)

```
#header-outer{
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 9998;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
padding: 28px 0px 0px;
overflow: visible !important;
height: 92px;
}
```